# matching query does not exist. in django

Tags: python, django, django-models

Hi This is my Project I needed define two get_absolute_url in my project
get_absolute_url one

models.py

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("cv:resume_detial", args={self.id, self.slug})
```

urls.py

```
path('resume-detial/<int:resume_id>/<slug:resume_slug>', views.ResumeDetialView.as_view(), name="resume_detial"),
```

views.py

```
class ResumeDetialView(View):
    template_name = 'cv/resume-detial.html'
    
    def get(self, request, resume_id, resume_slug):
        resumes = ResumeDetial.objects.get(pk=resume_id, slug=resume_slug)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'resumes':resumes})
```

This is a work But other get_absolute_url is does not work

models.py

```
def get_absolute_url(self):
    return reverse("cv:project_detial", args={self.id, self.project_slug})
```

urls.py

```
path('project-detial/<int:project_id>/<slug:projects_slug>', views.ProjectDetialView.as_view(), name="project_detial"),
```

views.py

```
class ProjectDetialView(View):
    template_name = 'cv/project-detial.html'
    
    def get(self, request, project_id, projects_slug):
        projects = ResumeDetial.objects.get(pk=project_id, slug=projects_slug)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"projects":projects})
```

django messages

```
DoesNotExist at /project-detial/1/todo-django
ResumeDetial matching query does not exist.
```

I am a beginner and thank you for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing `ResumeDetial.objects.get(pk=project_id, slug=projects_slug)`
while the ResumeDetial with these criteria doesn't exist. You can use [filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/models/querysets/#filter) to search for ResumeDetial's with the given criteria, in case no results are found, it will return an empty list.

So, you can change this part of the code:

```
    def get(self, request, project_id, projects_slug):
        projects = ResumeDetial.objects.filter(pk=project_id, slug=projects_slug)
        return render(request, self.template_name, {"projects":projects})
```